# How many Flash objects/movies can you add to a page before memory consumption becomes an issue?

Tags: flash, memory-management

In an Ajax desktop scenario (iGoogle, Netvibes etc); how many separate Flash "widgets" can you load before memory usage becomes a problem?

Does each Flash  instantiate a separate Flash player?  Or is there just one Flash player / browser, so memory usage is only dependant on the memory requirements of the swf?

Or is this something that differs between browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flash itself runs fairly lightweight.  The actual movie content (big graphics for instance) and what it does (complex animations) will have a big impact here.  And of course, when asking about impact of memory consumption you should frame it in the context of target machine, because my machine with a gig of memory and proper virtual memory set up will do better than my mom's with 256k.  So, as with many things in programming, the answer is: it depends.

Answer (score 0):

Its Depends on your Physical Memory